# How do I access methods like $this->getChildHtml() in other directories/pages in Magento?

Tags: php, oop, magento

All I want to do is move a search box. This search box is currently displayed in the header, directly next to the logo, and is generated by the following code:

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>`

in `/app/design/frontend/MYTHEME/default/template/page/html/header.phtml`

I would like this search box inline with the navigation links, which are located in `top.phtml` which is located in another directory. But when I use the code

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>`

the search box does not appear. I understand that this is because the meaning of `$this` has changed, but what I don't understand is how to display the search box? What do I replace `$this` with?

I tried replacing it with `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Header` since that was the definition of `$this` in header.phtml, but to no avail. Can anybody point me in the right direction, or provide an explanation as to how I access methods once the definition of `$this` has changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make layout update and include block topSearch into block containing top.phtml.
Look into app/design/frontend/.../layouts/...xml files, find how topSearch is declared and then find where the block using top.phtml template is declared. Then move topSearch block as a child of top block. I mean add layout xml update like this:

```
<default>
    <reference name="catalog.topnav">
        <block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Another solution is try next in your template:

```
echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('top.search')->toHtml()
```

If it would not work then find in layouts topSearch block and try to use in code above name of block instead of alias.

You can read more about Magento view level here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/0_-_theming_in_magento/designing-for-magento

Good luck!

Comment: Danke schön! I will try the methods suggested and look into the resource provided!

Comment: What do you mean by "move topSearch block as a child of top block"? Copy-and-paste the block into the file referencing top.phtml? I tried that, but don't really know where to paste it. Inside the <block> tag (that references top.phtml)? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I mean add layout update xml for your pages with this block as a child of navigation block. Please see updated answer with more examples